# Drupal 7 scope of global $user when creating module using jquery post

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am creating a module to populate the body of a drupal 7 page of mine.

I have 3 files I am working with.

```
1. league_settings.module
2. league_settings.js
3. league_settings.php
```

league_settings.module is as follows.

```
function league_settings_block_view($delta = '') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'league_settings') .'/js/jquery.js');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'league_settings') .'/js/json2.js');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'league_settings') .'/js/livequery.js');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'league_settings') .'/js/leagueSettings.js');

    $block = array(
      'subject' => t('Enabled Modules'),
      'content' => 'this text works',
     );
       return $block;
    }
```

league_settings.js is simply

```
$.post('/modules/leage_settings/php/leagueSettings.php', 
    function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

league_settings.php is

```
global $user;
$name = $user->name;
echo $name;
```

This will alert a black text box.  if I echo 'test' it will work properly.

At the moment I am unable to query without getting a error 500 on my post.  I have tried throwing global $user in a function to no avail.  Is creating a module like this the best way to set up a php/js file to query my drupal database and edit my page html?

Comment: Just curious, why not create pages through hook_menu?